# Why isn't the request body showing up in the Kubernetes API server audit log?

Tags: kubernetes, audit-logging, kube-apiserver

I have added the following command-line arguments to `kube-apiserver` to enable audit logging:

```
- --audit-log-path=/tmp/k8s-audit.log
- --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit.yaml
- --audit-log-maxage=1
- --audit-log-maxsize=100
- --audit-log-maxbackup=1
```

The contents of `/etc/kubernetes/audit.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
omitStages:
  - "ResponseStarted"
  - "ResponseComplete"
rules:
  - level: RequestResponse
```

I have run a command with verbose logging, so that I can see the request body:

```
$ kubectl --v=10 uncordon cluster-worker2
```

And the kubectl command logs the request body as follows:

```
I0328 09:00:07.591869   47228 request.go:942] Request Body: {"spec":{"unschedulable":null}}
```

But I don't see this request body anywhere in the audit log file on the kubernetes server. What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: do you have more than one API Server and if yes then checked in all of them ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu no, there is only one API server. I am using Kind (Kubernetes in docker).

Comment: Can you try an alternative command like `kubectl get pods`? Does that show up with a `RequestReceived`?

Comment: Why do you use `RequestResponse` level to log just a request body ? You should use `Request` level

Comment: @ALex_hha Ah yes, now that you mention it, I realise that was probably my real error. I did have a feeling that might be significant, but I thought it shouldn't go so badly wrong as to not log anything on the server. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is actually only logged in the `ResponseComplete` stage, somewhat unexpectedly. Even though Kubernetes *could* theoretically log the request as soon as it receives it, it doesn't.

So it's necessary to remove the `ResponseComplete` line from the `omitstages` in the policy configuration file (`audit.yaml`).